# The Akshaya Patra's legend in the Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

[Akshaya Patra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akshaya_Patra)

[Akshaya Patra](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.templepurohit.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F08%2FWhat-is-Akshaya-Patra-The-Mahabharata-Story-1.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.templepurohit.com%2Fwhat-is-akshaya-patra-miracle-of-akshaya-patra%2F&tbnid=eVr8ctyAsTXpnM&vet=1&docid=7ywV3iWeaWW3CM&w=640&h=400&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)

As per the Wikipedia, the Akshaya Patra was handed by King Surya to Yudhishthir.

Why not to Arjuna, Bheem, Sahadev & Nukul?

Is it because Yudhishthir was the eldest among the Pandavas and Yudhishthir prayed to King Surya ?

I mean in case Arjuna or Bheem would have prayed to King Surya then they could have got the Akshaya Patra from King Surya?

Comment: Hi, I have taken the liberty to edit your question a bit, keeping in mind [this META post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/purge-and-blacklist-the-mythology-tag) feel free to roll-back the edit, if you disagree with it. Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yudhishthira was blessed with the Akṣayapātra since he himself prayed for it. Also, he's the eldest amongst the lot (the familial sustainer/provider). It's his responsibility to maintain the family

> [Section III](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7276.html), Aranyaka Parva, Vana Parva
>
> "Vaisampayana said, 'Yudhishthira the son of Kunti, thus addressed by
> Saunaka, approached his priest and in the midst of his brothers said,
>
> 'The Brahmanas versed in the Vedas are following me who am departing
> for the forest. **Afflicted with many calamities I am unable to support
> them. I cannot abandon them, nor have I the power to offer them
> sustenance**: Tell me, O holy one, what should be done by me in such a
> pass.'

So we see it was Yudhishthira's concern for his kin and wife's sustenance, that led him to the prayer to the Sun-god and subsequently the Sun-god blessing them with a boon in the form of the vessel - akṣayapātra

And thus, satisfied with the prayers made by Yudhishthira, the Sun-god appeared and blessed him

> "Vaisampayana said, 'Thus, O great king, was the sun that purifier of
> the world, adored (by Yudhishthira).**And pleased with the hymn, the
> maker of day, self-luminous, and blazing like fire showed himself to
> the son of Pandu**. And Vivasvan said,
>
> 'You shall obtain all that you desirest.**I shall provide you with food
> for five and seven years together. And, O king, accept this
> copper-vessel which I give unto you. And, O you of excellent vows, as
> long as Pancali will hold this vessel, without partaking of its
> contents fruits and roots and meat and vegetables cooked in your
> kitchen, these four kinds of food shall from this day be
> inexhaustible.** And, on the fourteenth year from this, you shall regain
> your kingdom.'

Regarding your question -  "*would Arjuna, Bhima, et al get the akṣayapātra had they prayed for it?*"  - that's an Opinion-seeking question. Not within the site's scope.

Comment: Thanks. Though it's a Opinion seeking question, would you like to give your personal opinion?

Comment: Why not! They would have, I presume. Although, in the scenario of Pandavas, that is not very "dharmic" to pray, when their eldest is present, who should be ideally performing those 'rites'. @PrashantAkerkar